# Generating tabular output from jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file and I need to extract some data from  it.

```
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "Attachments": [],
            "Encrypted": true,
            "Size": 100,
            "SnapshotId": "",
            "State": "available",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim1"
                },

                {
                    "Key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name",
                    "Value": "pvc-claim1"
                }
            ],
            "VolumeType": "io1",
            "MultiAttachEnabled": false
        },
        {
            "Attachments": [],
            "Encrypted": true,
            "Size": 200,
            "SnapshotId": "",
            "State": "available",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name",
                    "Value": "pvc-claim2"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim2"
                }
            ],
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "MultiAttachEnabled": false
        }

    ]
}
```

I wanted to extract Tags values, whose keys are Name: For eg:

I wanted to get only kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim1 and kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim2.

I wanted results like:

```
kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim1
kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim2
```

How do I do that ? I have been struggling with jq and tried something like;

```
'jq -r .'Volumes[].Tags[0].Value'
```

But it is not giving me result as expected.

Also, how do I get output with Size and VOlumetype on their side as below ?

I wanted results like:

```
kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim1  100  io1
kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-claim2  200  gp2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the values in appropriate variables while traversing the JSON and put the final result into an array.

Run the `jq` command in `-r/--raw-output` mode when using `join(" ")`. You could also use `@csv` or `@tsv` instead, to put the results in CSV or TSV format.

```
.Volumes[] | 
.Size as $s | 
.VolumeType as $v | 
.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value as $k | 
[$k, $s, $v] | join(" ")
```

<sup>[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AiAOuqyFaC)</sup>